# Need to insert data into MySQL if there is one, and not if more than one

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, having

The SQL statement below should insert if the shop has only 1 company_id. I don't want to insert any data if there are 2 company_id already.

I don't know how to prevent inserting the data when there are 2 or more company_id's.

```
INSERT INTO customers (
    id, 
      name, 
      phone, 
      mail, 
      address
)
    SELECT 
      company.id, 
      company.name, 
      company.phone, 
      company.mail, 
      company.address, 
    FROM 
      company 
      LEFT JOIN shops ON company.id = shops.id 
    WHERE 
      shops.company_id IN (
        SELECT 
          company.id 
        FROM 
          company 
          LEFT JOIN shops ON company.id = shops.company_id 
        WHERE 
          shops.id IN (1,2,41)
      )
    GROUP BY 
      shops.company_id 
    having 
      count(shops.company_id) >= 1 ;
```

Comment: `I have a following query to insert the data` ... the query you showed us _retrieves_ data from your database, but it doesn't _insert_ it.  What do you mean by "insert the data" here?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Any explanation of the logic would help as well.

Comment: Need to see an example of your shops table.  If the same company_id can be in the shops table more than once then you will need :having 
      count(DISTINCT shops.company_id) >= 1 ;